# Probability that N random walkers are getting farther apart

Tags: probability, random-walk, standard-deviation

If two people start at 0 and walk with random direction in one dimension (with constant step-size), the probability that their distance from each other increases is 0.5 after a step, so the probability that the standard deviation of their positions increases is 0.5 -- $P_2(\Delta\sigma>0)=0.5$.

With three or more (N) people, my intuition is that this probability is larger for larger N, but I can't find the relationship analytically. I could simulate it to get approximations of $P_N(\Delta\sigma>0)$, but I'm interested in how straightforward the analytical solution might be.

---

Edit 1: At the first step from 0, since $\sigma$ is 0, $P_N(\Delta\sigma>0)$ = $1-(\frac{1}{2})^{N-1}$. For later steps I suppose $P$ is dependent on the current $\sigma$.

Edit 2: I initially wanted to solve this for step sizes drawn from a uniform distribution [-1,1], but that may make things overly complicated to start. I'll focus on only step sizes of -1 or +1.

Some work:

In a step, each $i^{th}$ person walks a distance $\delta_i$ (-1 or 1) from $x_{i,0}$ to $x_{i,1}$.

$$ x_{i,1} = x_{i,0} + \delta_i  $$
$$ \bar{x}_1 = \bar{x}_0 + \bar{\delta} $$
$$\sigma_1^2 - \sigma_0^2 = \frac{1}{N-1} (\sum_i |x_{i,1} - \bar{x}_{i,1}|^2 - |x_{i,0} - \bar{x}_{i,0}|^2)$$
$$ = \sum_i (\bar{\delta} - \delta_i)^2 + 2(\bar{x}_0-x_0)(\bar{\delta}-\delta_i)$$
$$P(\sigma_1^2 - \sigma_0^2 > 0) = ?$$

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you're discussing here: if $X_1, X_2$ are the positions of the walkers, are you talking about the standard deviation of those two numbers, i.e. $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2-1} [ (X_1 - \overline X)^2 + (x_2 - \overline X^2)]}$, where $\overline X = \frac 1 2 ( X_1+ X_2)$?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Yes, I'll clarify this above. Thanks

Comment: (1) I think you meant $P_N(\Delta \sigma = 0) = (\frac 1 2)^{N-1}$, not $P_N(\Delta \sigma > 0) = (\frac 1 2)^{N-1}$. (2) It's certainly true that $P$ depends on $\sigma$. (In fact, they may not be a function of $\sigma$ but may require full knowledge of the underlying $X_i$ values; I'd have to think more about that.) Consider the case where $X_1 = X_2 = 0$ and $X_3 = 100$; here, if all three walkers step right or step left, $\sigma$ is unchanged. Otherwise, $\sigma$ decreases when $X_3$ moves left and increases when $X_3$ moves right, irrespective of the behavior of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I think the answer to this wouldn't be very meaningful at all...

Comment: Really? I think it's an interesting question!

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Thanks, I was just expecting something more elegant; I guess I shouldn't judge until I find the answer. But for my application, I'm starting to think "standard deviation" isn't the metric I want.